# PHP OOP MySQL Programming

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop

I am a beginner in PHP programming and would like help with a little question.  Please take a look at the code below:

---

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
class Account
{
  public function register()
  {
    $db_link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  // Create Connection
    if (!$db_link)  // Check connection
    {
      die(mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($db_link); // Close Connection
  }

  public function login()
  {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")  // create connection
    if (!$con)  // create connection
    {
      die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_close($con); //close connection
  }

}
?>
```

---

My question is if creating individual db links for every single one of the object's methods is the best way to go?  Is there a better or alternative way to do this? Hopefully I've explained well enough.

---

Would the following be correct?

```
$x = new Account("localhost", "root", "");
```

-and x would have its own connection...and then close when its done?

Comment: Just use `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_close()` at the beginning and at the end of your whole program. There is no need to instantiate a connection at every method.

Comment: @ldiqual: your comment could be an answer!

Comment: @idiqual You should not be encouraging the use of `mysql_` at all, particularly for somebody just coming into the language and is starting a new project.

Comment: if you want to keep db to the Accounting class connect in your `__construct` and implement `__destruct` method to destroy connection when object is destroyed.

Comment: Use singleton pattern.
Example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685896/check-if-a-specific-mysql-connection-already-exists-during-a-php-script/8685944#8685944

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not advise creating your database connections this way.  Create one connection and inject that into the object using it.  You should not need to create a new connection for every object.

Code example:

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password');

$Account = new Account($connection);
```

Would need to change `Account` to look like:

```
class Account {

    protected $connection;

    public function __construct(mysqli $connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function register() {
        // use $this->connection for db
    }

    public function login() {
        // use $this->connection for db
    }

}
```

---

I would also suggest that you take a look at the [php.net docs about choosing a MySQL API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  If you really want to use OOP with PHP and MySQL you will need to swap over to `mysqli` or `PDO` as the API you are using does not truly support an OOP interface.

Comment: You forgot to close the connection.

Comment: @GabrielSantos No, I didn't close it on purpose.  What if there's another object that needs to use that connection?  Then we have to open the connection again.  The code that created the connection object should be responsible for closing the connection.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

```
public function __construct(mysqli $connection) {
    $this->connection = $connection;
    if(!$this->$connection) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}

public function __destruct() {
    mysql_close($this->$connection);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd recommend using die in this (or any OO) situation.

Comment: @cbuckley It is only for sample purpose.

Comment: My only concern was that it might be a bad example to set to a beginner PHP programmer, OOP or otherwise.

Comment: No, is not. die have not relation to OOP.

Comment: Exception handling is an integral part of OOP. die() immediately produces fatal errors. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845494/php-oop-exceptions-or-die

Comment: I know, but, I can't do a try..catch block ever. One time I will need to call die();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6325/discussion-between-cbuckley-and-gabriel-santos)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some codes like as:

```
$db_link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  // Create Connection
if (!$db_link)  // Check connection 
{
  die(mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("db_name");
$q=mysql_query("SELECET * FROM table_name LIMIT 1");
```

Other queries would be here

```
mysql_close($db_link); // Close Connection
```

Creating single connection at each page is enough. more than one connection or disconnecting from sql server and loginning again may cause reduced performance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a static member and all your objects will share one database connection.

See also 
[PHP - a DB abstraction layer use static class vs singleton object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840912/php-a-db-abstraction-layer-use-static-class-vs-singleton-object)

Comment: I wouldn't use neither (static class or singleton).

Comment: Downvote for singleton.  No reason to introduce a database connection into the global scope with static

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry Agree again.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to shrink it and keep it neater/more manageable you could put the mysql connect code into it's own method and call it like so:

```
<?php
class Account
{
  private $connection;

  private function connect()
  {
    $this->$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  // Create Connection
  }

  public function register()
  {
    $this->connect();
    if (!$this->$connection)  // Check connection
    {
      die(mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($this->$connection); // Close Connection
  }

  public function login()
  {
    $this->connect();
    if (!$this->$connection)  // create connection
    {
      die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_close($this->$connection); //close connection
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: Downvoted because ultimately you're still creating the database connection every time a function is called.

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry Agree with you.

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry I misinterpreted the original question